# uniform angular distribution-change of origin

Tags: trigonometry, probability-distributions, mathematical-physics

Given a variable which is uniformly distributed for $0<\theta<\pi$ on, let's say, a circle around the origin $O$ with radius $R$($\theta$ starting on the positive x-axis and turning counterclockwise). Now, I introduce a new origin $O'$ with cartesic coordinates in the original frame $(-d,0)$, both $d<R$ as $d>R$ are considered. Now, I define from $O'$, $\phi$ as the angle between the positive x-axis and a point on the circle.

if the probability density as a function of $\theta$ is equal to a constant $C$ everywhere(and hence normalized to $\pi C$), we should be able to write
$$C\, d\theta=f(\phi)d\phi$$.

Now my question is: What is the expression for $f$?

I initially thought this would be an easy problem, but it turns out less trivial than we were expecting. We encountered this problem by studying galilei transformations of circularly symmetric collisions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but you can connect $\theta$ and $\phi$ with the following relationship obtained using trigonometry: $$\tan\phi=\frac {R\sin\theta}{d+R\cos\theta}$$